# Python function help

Tags: python, function

Please help! cannot figure this out for the life of me

> Given the function `f(x,n)= n**x(n-1)`
>
> 5c. Using this function, calculate the rate of change of `(((2^3 + 3^2)^4 -2^4)^2 + (3^4 – (6^2 + 3)^4)^3)^3`

This is what I came up with in IDLE:

```
def function(x, n):
    return (n*(x**(n-1)))

assertEqual (
  function ((((
    function (2.0, 3.0))+(
      function (3.0, 2.0)), 4.0)-(
        function (2.0, 4.0)), 2.0)+((
          function (3.0, 4.0))-((
            function (6.0, 2.0))+(
              function (3.0, 1.0)), 4.0), 3.0), 3.0), 35994405888.0)
```

and after I save and run it, I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan Cohen\Desktop\School\CISC 106\lab2.py", line 83, in <module>
    assertEqual (function ((((function (2.0, 3.0))+(function (3.0, 2.0)), 4.0)-(function (2.0, 4.0)), 2.0)+((function (3.0, 4.0))-((function (6.0, 2.0))+(function (3.0, 1.0)), 4.0), 3.0), 3.0), 35994405888.0)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float'
```

Comment: the line of code is too complex. Break it into multiple lines.

Comment: What is "function"? Where is it defined? Can you please show the code for it? I suspect that "function" returns a tuple, which is the source of your bug. Try something like AssertEqual(funtion(funtion(...), ...), 35994405888.0)

Comment: I originally posted this as an answer, but it's really a comment: in Python a tuple is represented by 0 or more comma-separated objects surrounded by parentheses, so the following is a tuple:

    (function(2.0, 3.0), 3.0)

This is easily confused with a method invocation which looks like `function_name(arg0, arg1)` - i.e. a function name followed by an argument list which looks very similar to a tuple. Somewhere in the expression you're invoking you're missing a `function`. I'll try to the find the exact location for you and post the result of my investigation...

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity, I'm new to the site. Here's the other information that might clear things up:

def function(x, n):
    return (n*(x**(n-1)))

again if I forgot to include some information please let me know and also thanks again for all your help!

Comment: The real question is wtf does calculating the rate of change of a constant mean.

Comment: ++humor points @Wooble. I was literally on the floor (yes, I actually fell off my chair) when I read that comment.

Comment: `<pedant>` @inspectorG4dget surely you were *actually* on the floor, not *literally*... `</pedant>` And also, yes @wooble OP spectacularly screwing his homework up.

Comment: @danodonovan : what's wrong with literally ? (english not being my mother tongue, this actually is a real question)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I think I may have [quite literally](http://www.guardian.co.uk/politics/reality-check-with-polly-curtis/2012/mar/12/reality-check-literally-wrong-use-word) incorrect. Apologies

Answer (score 3):

`(function(a, b), c)` is a 2-tuple consisting of the result of `function(a,b)` and `c`.

If you want to represent `(a^b)^c`, you'd need something like `function(function(a,b), c)` (assuming `function()` computes its first parameter raised to the second.)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few occurances of this, but here is the first one.

```
function ((((function (2.0, 3.0))+(function (3.0, 2.0)), 4.0)-(function (2.0, 4.0)), 2.0)+((function (3.0, 4.0))-((function (6.0, 2.0))+(function (3.0, 1.0)), 4.0), 3.0), 3.0)
           ((function (2.0, 3.0))+(function (3.0, 2.0)), 4.0)
```

The segment that I've blocked out, produces a tuple of `(18.0, 4.0)`. You then try to do normal math on this, which fails.

---

In response to the comment, this particular segment would work better if you did the following:

```
function((function (2.0, 3.0))+(function (3.0, 2.0)), 4.0)
```

Comment: how can I correct this segment then?

Answer (score 1):

This starts off looking like calculus to me, but quickly goes off the rails.

Elementary differential calculus says that if you have a function:

[image]

then the first derivative with respect to the independent variable x is:

[image]

It looks to me like you're trying to evaluate something like this with Python, but the tuple expression you give makes no sense to me.  Was there supposed to be an independent variable hidden in there somewhere?

Comment: agreed. I stared at this question several times today, saw the derivative connection, but still could make no sense of the question.

Answer (score 0):

So after two weeks of pulling my hair out trying to figure this out I think I finally got it.  Thanks so much everybody, all your input really helped! I broke down each part and rewrote everything according to what you all suggested. This is what I came up with:

```
def function (x,n):
    return (n*(x**(n-1)))

assertEqual (function (function (function((function (2, 3))+(function (3, 2)), 4)-function(function (2, 4), 1), 2)+function (function ((function (3,4)),1)-function ((function (6,2))+(function (3,1)),4),3),3), 161027925052617363)
```

after saving it and running it, the Python shell tells me it's successful, what do you all say?

Once again thanks for all your help!

Comment: Where did you get 161027925052617363 from? or 35994405888.0 (from the original question)? How do you know which, if either one, is the correct answer? There's still a lot of info missing here.

Comment: I still say it's absolute crap, regardless of whether or not the Python shell accepted it and gave you an answer.  The value for x ought to be the same for each function call if you're evaluating at a particular point, but it's not.  It's either a bad assignment, a poor implementation, or both.